# Only Last Date Result per Order? How?

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, where-clause

so basicaly i got this Table

```
OrderID|       ChangeDate      | 
-------|-----------------------|
Order1 |2013-03-17 14:40:47.000|
Order1 |2013-03-20 16:09:09.000|
Order2 |2013-03-12 12:34:09.000|
Order3 |2013-03-20 18:30:12.000|
Order2 |2013-03-20 12:39:49.000|
```

What i want and need, is Only the Top one of Each OrderID,
(right now i'm getting around 28000 results[the whole table], with each Order 100 times or so)
I only need the top one (last change date)
the current query that i have looks something like this:

```
Select
     a.AuftragID
    ,a.Kunde
    ,max(ChangeDate)
From Orders O innerJoin
     factTable F on O.OrderID = F.OrderID
Group by a.AuftragID
        ,a.Kunde
```

What can i do to get only the Top Result (Latest changeDate Result) per Order
As Always, very greatefull for your Help!

Comment: what is `a.AuftragID`, which table is represented by `a` ?

Comment: Auftrag in German is order. I assume they're translating to English. There is probably a table called aufträge for orders.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT F.auftragid, 
                F.kunde, 
                changedate, 
                rn = Row_number() 
                     OVER( 
                       partition BY O.orderid 
                       ORDER BY changedate DESC) 
         FROM   orders O 
                INNER JOIN facttable F 
                        ON O.orderid = F.orderid) 
SELECT auftragid, 
       kunde, 
       changedate 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  rn = 1
```

( note that i've presumed that the alias in your sample query is a type and `a` actually is `f`)

[**TSQL Ranking Functions**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

Comment: You're right. damn copy-paste on the OP! haha +1 for, just deleted my answer `:D`

Comment: @JW: Thanks, preserved your ranking-functions link.

Answer (score 0):

Limit the return to one:

```
Select
     a.AuftragID
    ,a.Kunde
    ,max(ChangeDate)
From Aufträge a, factTable F
where a.AuftragID = F.OrderID
Group by a.AuftragID
     ,a.Kunde
order by a.AuftragID DESC
limit 1
```